# Null properties are dropped during marshalling/unmarshalling with JSONIX

Tags: jsonix

I noticed that in my conversion from JSON to XML, if one of my JSON objects is null, the object is absent from the XML, for example

JSON

`{
    "name": {
        "namespaceURI": "",
        "localPart": "myApp",
        "prefix": "",
        "key": "myApp",
        "string": "myApp"
    },
    "value": {
        "TYPE_NAME": "generated.MyApp",
        "inputData": [{
            "TYPE_NAME": "generated.MyApp.InputData",
            "dataType": "text",
            "mandatory": false,
            "length": 25,
            "valid": true,
                        "value":null
        }]
    }
}`

Convert to XML output (marshalString)

`var context2 = new j.Context([generated2]);
        var marshaller2 = context2.createMarshaller();
        var objectAsXMLString2 = marshaller2.marshalString(template2);`

`<myApp>
   <inputData>
      <dataType>text</dataType>
      <mandatory>false</mandatory>
      <length>25</length>
      <valid>true</valid>
   </inputData>
</myApp>`

Then converting back again to JSON (unmarshalString)

`var unmarshaller2 = context2.createUnmarshaller();
        var resultJSON2 = unmarshaller2.unmarshalString(objectAsXMLString2 );`

`{
    "name": {
        "namespaceURI": "",
        "localPart": "myApp",
        "prefix": "",
        "key": "myApp",
        "string": "myApp"
    },
    "value": {
        "TYPE_NAME": "generated.MyApp",
        "inputData": [{
            "TYPE_NAME": "generated.MyApp.InputData",
            "dataType": "text",
            "mandatory": false,
            "length": 25,
            "valid": true
        }]
    }
}`

So as you see, there is loss of information.  When the complete cycle of conversion occurs, JSON -> XML -> back to JSON, some properties are not preserved.  Anything  that is null gets dropped - in this case it is the property 'value'.  This is a problem for downstream applications that are expecting certain properties to be present on an object.

My XML schema that was used to generate the jsonix mapping object looks like this

`<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="myApp">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="inputData" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence >
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dataType"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="mandatory"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="length"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="elementId"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:string" name="formId"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:anySimpleType" name="value" />
              <xs:element type="xs:boolean" name="valid"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="precision"/>
              <xs:element type="xs:short" name="scale"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>`

And generated mapping using jsonix-schema-compiler  is

`var generated_Module_Factory = function () {
  var generated = {
    name: 'generated',
    typeInfos: [{
        localName: 'MyApp',
        typeName: null,
        propertyInfos: [{
            name: 'inputData',
            minOccurs: 0,
            collection: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'inputData'
            },
            typeInfo: '.MyApp.InputData'
          }]
      }, {
        localName: 'MyApp.InputData',
        typeName: null,
        propertyInfos: [{
            name: 'dataType',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'dataType'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'mandatory',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'mandatory'
            },
            typeInfo: 'Boolean'
          }, {
            name: 'length',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'length'
            },
            typeInfo: 'Short'
          }, {
            name: 'elementId',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'elementId'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'formId',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'formId'
            }
          }, {
            name: 'value',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'value'
            },
            typeInfo: 'AnySimpleType'
          }, {
            name: 'valid',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'valid'
            },
            typeInfo: 'Boolean'
          }, {
            name: 'precision',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'precision'
            },
            typeInfo: 'Short'
          }, {
            name: 'scale',
            required: true,
            elementName: {
              localPart: 'scale'
            },
            typeInfo: 'Short'
          }]
      }],
    elementInfos: [{
        typeInfo: '.MyApp',
        elementName: {
          localPart: 'myApp'
        }
      }]
  };
  return {
    generated: generated
  };
};
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define([], generated_Module_Factory);
}
else {
  var generated_Module = generated_Module_Factory();
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports.generated = generated_Module.generated;
  }
  else {
    var generated = generated_Module.generated;
  }
}`

Is there a way to preserve all properties during the conversion, even if they are null?

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment.

I think what you're looking for is support for `nillable` elements as you probably want to distinguish `null` vs. absent property vs. property with the empty string as value.

Jsonix does not support `nillable` elements at the moment.